# Python: web login script, what's the problem?

Tags: python, browser

this is the script >>

```
import ClientForm
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request("http://ritaj.birzeit.edu")

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
forms = ClientForm.ParseResponse(response, backwards_compat=False)
response.close()

form = forms[0]
print form
sooform = str(raw_input("Form Name: "))
username = str(raw_input("Username: "))
password = str(raw_input("Password: "))

form[sooform] = [username, password]

request2 = form.click()
try:
    response2 = urllib2.urlopen(request2)
except urllib2.HTTPError, response2:
    pass

print response2.geturl()
print response2.info()  # headers
print response2.read()  # body
response2.close()
```

when start the script ,, i got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/ritaj2.py", line 9, in <module>
    form = forms[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

what is th problem,, i running on windows, python 2.6.4

**Update:**

I want a script that login this site, and print the response :)

Comment: How long did you investigate the problem yourself?

Comment: i'm trying to make this script about two days ago,, and got nothing and every time i got a code, it shows a error,, so if you can help me in make login script for this site i will be thankful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only `<form>` tag in the HTML served at that URL (save it to a file and look for yourself!) is:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://www.google.com/u/ritaj">
```

which does a customized Google search and has nothing to do with logging in (plus, for some reason, ClientForm has some problem identifying that specific form -- but that form is no use to you anyway, so I didn't explore that issue further).

You can still get at the **controls** in the page by using

```
forms = ClientForms.ParseResponseEx(response)
```

which makes `forms[0]` an artificial one containing all controls that aren't within a form.

Specifically, this approach identifies controls with the following names, in order (again there's a bit of parsing confusion here, but hopefully not a killer for you...):

```
>>> f = forms[0]
>>> [c.name for c in f.controls]
['q', 'sitesearch', 'sa', 'domains', 'form:mode', 'form:id', '__confirmed_p', '__refreshing_p', 'return_url', 'time', 'token_id', 'hash', 'username', 'password', 'persistent_p', 'formbutton:ok']
```

so you should be able to set the `username` and `password` controls of the "non-form form" `f`, and proceed from there.

(A side bit: `raw_input` already returns a string, lose those redundant `str()` calls around it).

Answer (score 0):

the actual address seems to be using `https` instead of `http`. check the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) doc to see if it handles HTTPS( i believe you need ssl)

Comment: yes its using https, and i'm new on python programming so can you help me please in this :)